# How to (massively) reduce the number of SQL queries in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have `users` which can have many `invoices` which in turn can have many `payments`.

Now in the `dashboard` view I want to summarize all the `payments` a `user` has ever received, ordered either by year, quarter, or month. The `payments` are also subdivided into *gross*, *net*, and *tax*.

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :invoices
  has_many  :payments

  def years
    (first_year..current_year).to_a.reverse
  end

  def year_ranges
    years.map { |y| Date.new(y,1,1)..Date.new(y,-1,-1) }
  end

  def quarter_ranges
    ...
  end

  def month_ranges
    ...
  end

  def revenue_between(range, kind)
    payments_with_invoice ||= payments.includes(:invoice => :items).all
    payments_with_invoice.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount") 
  end

end
```

**invoice.rb**:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  has_many :payments

  def total
    items.sum(&:total)
  end

  def subtotal
    items.sum(&:subtotal)
  end

  def total_tax
    items.sum(&:total_tax)
  end

end
```

**payment.rb**:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :invoice  

  def percent_of_invoice_total
    (100 / (invoice.total / amount.to_d)).abs.round(2)
  end

  def net_amount
    invoice.subtotal * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end  

  def taxable_amount
    invoice.total_tax * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

  def gross_amount
    invoice.total * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

end
```

**dashboards_controller**:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

  def index    
    if %w[year quarter month].include?(params[:by])   
      range = params[:by]
    else
      range = "year"
    end
    @ranges = @user.send("#{range}_ranges")
  end

end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<% @ranges.each do |range| %>

  <%= render :partial => 'range', :object => range %>

<% end %>
```

**_range.html.erb**:

```
<%= @user.revenue_between(range, :gross) %>
<%= @user.revenue_between(range, :taxable) %>
<%= @user.revenue_between(range, :net) %>
```

Now the problem is that this approach works but produces an awful lot of SQL queries as well. In a typical `dashboard` view I get **100+** SQL queries. Before adding `.includes(:invoice)` there were even more queries.

I assume one of the major problems is that each invoice's `subtotal`, `total_tax` and `total` aren't stored anywhere in the database but instead calculated with every request.

Can anybody tell me how to speed up things here? I am not too familiar with SQL and the inner workings of ActiveRecord, so that's probably the problem here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should look at the SQL requests to find which pieces of information are needed, and use `includes` (as you done for invoice) to include them in the first request. If you can't find it, please add the SQL requests to your question.

Comment: Have a look at the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), which detects where you can reduce queries by using eager loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever `revenue_between` is called, it fetches the `payments` in the given time range and the associated `invoices` and `items` from the db. Since the time ranges have lot of overlap (month, quarter, year), same records are being fetched over and over again.

I think it is better to fetch all the payments of the user once, then filter and summarize them in Ruby.

To implement, change the `revenue_between` method as follows:

```
def revenue_between(range, kind) 
   #store the all the payments as instance variable to avoid duplicate queries
   @payments_with_invoice ||= payments.includes(:invoice => :items).all
   @payments_with_invoice.select{|x| range.cover? x.created_at}.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount") 
end
```

This would eager load all the payments along with associated invoices and items.

Also change the `invoice` summation methods so that it uses the eager loaded `items`

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

   def total
     items.map(&:total).sum
   end

   def subtotal
     items.map(&:subtotal).sum
   end

   def total_tax
     items.map(&:total_tax).sum
   end

end
```

Comment: Very good point, thank you very much. Your code reduces the number of SQL queries dramatically when I use `.sum(&:amount_in_cents)`. There are no more N+1 queries that way. I assume that's because ActiveRecord can fetch the amounts directly from the database that way. However, when using `.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount")` I still get dozens of queries per `range`. I guess that's because all these methods will have to be calculated for each `payment` (see `Payment` model code above). So can this be avoided by adding additional database columns for `net_amount`, `taxable_amount`, and `gross_amount`?

Comment: how is invoice.total invoice.subtotal etc caculated. can you post the code for those.

Comment: I mean how are they calculated for an `invoice`

Comment: Yes, I just posted my `Invoice` model in my initial post above. Indeed they are being calculated. But I wouldn't mind to store them somewhere in the database.

Comment: Just tried it but won't change anything. No impact on the number of queries whatsoever.

Comment: cant see why not...will need to see the query log..are you sure that the classes were reloaded, since we are storing the association in an instance variable.

Comment: OK, this would be the [query log](http://pastie.org/8366685). Looks to me like it's fetching a lot of `items` there. Yes, I restarted the server a couple of times to reload the classes.

Comment: lot happening there!..added `.all` after the `includes`, give that a try...also anything with `CACHE` in the query log is not really a query to db so ignore those for now.

Comment: `.all` doesn't change anything either, I'm afraid. I am using [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) to count my database queries and I am still getting an awful lot of them there per range (cached queries not included). Looks like I have to create database columns for the payment `net_amount`, `taxable_amount`, and `gross_amount`? Because that will definitely solve it. Don't like the extra columns, though... :-(

Comment: should be definitely possible without adding the columns, post the controller and views as well...there is something small here.

Comment: OK, I posted an update above. I also added the method in the User model as I have it now. I realize that I am not using an instance variable there as you suggested. But I think that can't be part of the problem, can it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: need to have it as an instance variable otherwise it is not saved and queried again, that will solve part of the problem only though

Comment: something funky is going on here see this [queston](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100618/activerecord-includes-how-to-use-map-with-loaded-associations) as well.

Comment: updated the answer, it is a bit of overkill but the idea is to do all invoice operations in `payment` model itself using `map` and also including `items` in the association itself. This scheme has worked for me in my app.

Comment: That works!! Wow, you're a genius. No more N+1 queries now! Fantastic! Thank you!!

Comment: I remember now that I ran into something very similar as well a few months ago.

Comment: great..if you don't mind I would like to see why it was not working before...can you try with everything same except the `:include => :items` in the `Payments` model and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Maybe in few months or years I will actually understand *why* your solution works and mine didn't.

Comment: One issue was using `sum` in the `invoice` model. It was ignoring the eagerly loaded items and querying the db again. Arel calculations like `sum` `maximum` `count` do not eager load.

Comment: OK, more more thing: I just realised that I don't need to change my `Payment` model at all. It's in the `Invoice` class that I have to do this: `items.map { |i| i.total_tax }.sum`. This makes your solution even more beautiful.

Comment: ya you can do that in `Invoice` model as well

Comment: updated the answer with a little more compact syntax.

Comment: Thank you. You really made my day. I just changed my variable to an instance variable (`@payments_with_invoice`) and I can observe how much faster it is now. I wonder why. I've never used an instance variable in a model before. Only in my controllers.

Comment: it is a nice technique see this useful [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables?view=asciicast) on it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the memoizing strategy proposed by @tihom, I suggest you have a look at the [Bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), that as they say in the description, it will help you kill N+1 queries and unused eager loading.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your data do not need to be real time. You can have a service calculating the stats and storing them wherever you want (Redis, cache...). Then refresh them every 10 minutes or upon user's request.

In the first place, render your page without stats and load them with ajax.

Comment: OK, thanks. Creating a `service` sounds complicated for someone who hasn't done a lot of Rails work before. Would `caching` be a simpler alternative to this? I could simply sweep the cache when a new `invoice` or `payment` is created by the user.

Comment: beware of cache: it's not persisted. Redis could be a good alternative. Or create a model which would bear the history of stats