# How to update instance variable in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instance-variables

In my Rails app I have `users` who can have many `payments`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invoices
  has_many :payments

  def year_ranges
    ...
  end

  def quarter_ranges
    ...
  end

  def month_ranges
    ...
  end

  def revenue_between(range, kind)
    payments.sum_within_range(range, kind)
  end

end
```

---

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  has_many :payments

  ...

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :invoice

  def net_amount
    invoice.subtotal * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end  

  def taxable_amount
    invoice.total_tax * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

  def gross_amount
    invoice.total * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

  def self.chart_data(ranges, unit)
    ranges.map do |r| { 
      :range            => range_label(r, unit),
      :gross_revenue    => sum_within_range(r, :gross),
      :taxable_revenue  => sum_within_range(r, :taxable),
      :net_revenue      => sum_within_range(r, :net) }
    end
  end

  def self.sum_within_range(range, kind)
    @sum ||= includes(:invoice => :items)
    @sum.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount")
  end

end
```

In my `dashboard` view I am listing the total payments for the `ranges` depending on the GET parameter that the user picked. The user can pick either `years`, `quarters`, or `months`.

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def show  
    if %w[year quarter month].include?(params[:by])   
      @unit = params[:by]
    else
      @unit = 'year'
    end
    @ranges = @user.send("#{@unit}_ranges")
    @paginated_ranges = @ranges.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @title = "All your payments"
  end

end
```

The use of the instance variable (`@sum`) greatly reduced the number of SQL queries here because the database won't get hit for the same queries over and over again.

The problem is, however, that when a user creates, deletes or changes one of his `payments`, this is not reflected in the `@sum` instance variable. So how can I reset it? Or is there a better solution to this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing the association as an instance variable of the Class `Payment`, store it as an instance variable of a `user` (I know it sounds confusing, I have tried to explain below)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments

  def revenue_between(range)
    @payments_with_invoices ||= payments.includes(:invoice => :items).all
    # @payments_with_invoices is an array now so cannot use Payment's class method on it
    @payments_with_invoices.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&:total)
  end

end
```

When you defined `@sum` in a class method (class methods are denoted by `self.`) it became an instance variable of Class `Payment`. That means you can potentially access it as `Payment.sum`. So this has nothing to do with a particular user and his/her payments. `@sum` is now an attribute of the class `Payment` and Rails would cache it the same way it caches the method definitions of a class.

Once `@sum` is initialized, it will stay the same, as you noticed, even after user creates new payment or if a different user logs in for that matter! It will change when the app is restarted.

However, if you define `@payments_with_invoices`like I show above, it becomes an attribute of a particular instance of `User` or in other words instance level instance variable. That means you can potentially access it as `some_user.payments_with_invoices`. Since an app can have many users these are not persisted in Rails memory across requests. So whenever the user instance changes its attributes are loaded again.

So if the user creates more payments the `@payments_with_invoices` variable would be refreshed since the user instance is re-initialized.

Comment: +1, good workaround. Though i would let `sum_within_range` do all the calculations using SQL (see my answer)

Comment: @m_x ya usually that would be better, but I had some bkgrnd due to a prev question. This function is being called numerous times in same request for overlapping ranges so I thought it is better to do the filtering in Rails. But if that is not the case anymore your solution makes more sense :)

Comment: Thanks. When I copy your exact code, I still get around 80 SQL queries. So I moved `includes(:invoice => :items)` to the beginning of the select method in the `Payment` class and now I get only around 10 SQL queries per page (which is the same as before and thus fine), however the total rendering time has increased an awful lot, from around 300 ms to around 3000 ms. That's definitely too much and I wonder why it is.

Comment: try @m_x's suggestion it might be faster.

Comment: I updated my solution as well for consistency but do not think it will speed it up

Comment: @Tintin81 maybe some context info on how this method is called would help us help you (controller code, view code...)

Comment: OK, I posted some more details above. Technically **m_x**'s solution is correct. However, the `net_amount`, `gross_amount` and `taxable_amount` are calculated for each `payment`, so I can't use scopes here (or at least I haven't managed to do so in the past). The solution that **tihom** provided to one of my [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077000/how-to-massively-reduce-the-number-of-sql-queries-in-rails-app) really helped me a lot and reduced the page loading time to around 200 ms for every page.

Comment: The only remaining problem is that I don't know how to reset `@sum` to reflect changes in the `user's` payments. As you can see from my code I am using `sum_within_range` all over the place (in a chart amongst others), so I think it's generally a good idea to somehow store all the user's payments in a variable, so it has to be loaded only once.

Answer (score 3):

This is incidental to your question, but don't use `#select` with a block.

What you're doing is selecting **all** payments, and then filtering the relation as an array. Use Arel to overcome this :

```
scope :within_range, ->(range){ where date: range }
```

This will build an SQL BETWEEN statement. Using `#sum` on the resulting relation will build an SQL SUM() statement, which is probably more efficient than loading all the records.

Comment: The `select` is an ActiveRecord Query method, not Arrays. It's just another chain on scope.

Comment: nope, not when using it with a block. Try it yourself : it will load all the records.

Comment: proof : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select . "with a block, works just like Array#select" see source...

Comment: this is a better solution if the method is called for few ranges in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it with observers:

```
# payment.rb

def self.cached_sum(force=false)
  if @sum.blank? || force
    @sum = includes(:invoice => :items)
  end
  @sum
end

def self.sum_within_range(range)
  @sum = cached_sum
  @sum.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&total)
end

#payment_observer.rb

class PaymentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  # force @sum updating

  def after_save(comment)
    Payment.cached_sum(true)
  end

  def after_destroy(comment)
    Payment.cached_sum(true)
  end

end
```

You could find more about observers at http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Observer

Answer (score 0):

Well your `@sum` is basically a cache of the values you need. Like any cache, you need to invalidate it if something happens to the values involved.

You could use `after_save` or `after_create` filters to call a function which sets `@sum = nil`. It may also be useful to also save the range your cache is covering and decide the invalidation by the date of the new or changed payment.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  after_save :invalidate_cache

  def self.sum_within_range(range)
    @cached_range = range
    @sum ||= includes(:invoice => :items)
    @sum.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&total)
  end

  def self.invalidate_cache
    @sum = nil if @cached_range.includes?(payment_date)
end
```